# Why aren't my template's if clauses update reactively?

Tags: javascript, meteor, helper, spacebars

For whatever reason I am unable to solve this issue with countless hours of troubleshooting. I have some simple helpers working with a Bootstrap 3 `nav-tabs` list.

I want to render a different template based on which list item is active. Here are my helpers:

```
Template.Profile.helpers({
  'personal':function(){
    if($('.profile-info').hasClass('active')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  'groups':function(){
    if($('.profile-groups').hasClass('active')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  },
  'commitments':function(){
    if($('.profile-commitments').hasClass('active')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active profile-info"><a href="#">Personal Info</a></li>
    <li class="profile-groups"><a href="#">Groups</a></li>
    <li class="profile-commitments"><a href="#">Commitments</a></li>
</ul>

{{#if personal}}
    {{> ProfilePersonal}}
{{else}}
    {{#if groups}}
        {{> ProfileGroups}}
    {{else}}
        {{> ProfileCommits}}
    {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Check what your helpers actually returning,  T or F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helpers will not be re-run when you click a tab, as there is no reactive data change to invalidate the computation.

A more Meteor-ish approach would be to add a reactive variable to hold the tab state and change that in an event listener.

```
<template name="Profile">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  {{#each tabs}}
    <li class="{{isActive @index}} profile-{{name}}"><a href="#">{{title}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{> Template.dynamic template=tpl}}
</template>
```

`@index` references the index of the current loop, and it's provided as an argument to the `isActive` helper.

Then, your JavaScript file can include a definition for the tabs and the handling code:

```
var tabs = [{
  idx: 0,
  name: "info",
  title: "Personal Info",
  template: "ProfilePersonal"
}, {
  idx: 1,
  name: "groups",
  title: "Groups",
  template: "ProfileGroups"
}, {
  idx: 2,
  name: "commitments",
  title: "Commitments",
  template: "ProfileCommits"
}];
```

The tabs are a plain JS array. The following code uses them in the template's context:

```
Template.Profile.helpers({
  // get current sub-template name
  tpl: function() {
    var tpl = Template.instance();
    return tabs[tpl.tabIdx.get()].template;
  },
  // get the tabs array
  tabs: function() {
    return tabs;
  },
  // compare the active tab index to the current index in the #each loop.
  isActive: function(idx) {
    var tpl = Template.instance();
    return tpl.tabIdx.get() === idx ? "active" : "";
  }
});

Template.Profile.events({
  'click .nav-tabs > li': function(e, tpl) {
    tpl.tabIdx.set(this.idx);
  }
});

Template.Profile.onCreated(function() {
  this.tabIdx = new ReactiveVar();
  this.tabIdx.set(0);
});
```

When the template is created (`onCreated()`), a new reactive variable is added as an instance variable. This variable can then be accessed in helpers and set in event handlers.

The event handler receives the event object and template instance as parameters and has the data context set as the `this` pointer; therefore, `tpl.tabIdx`refers the reactive variable and `this` refers to the object that represents the clicked tab (for example,

```
{
  idx: 0,
  name: "info",
  title: "Personal Info",
  template: "ProfilePersonal"
}
```

for the first tab, as this was the template's data context when the first tab was rendered.

The helper functions get the `Template` instance using a call to `Template.instance()`. Then, it queries the value of the reactive array.

This creates a computation in a reactive context (helpers are reactive contexts and they are rerun when the computation they create is invalidated, and that happens when an Mongo cursor, or a reactive variable that is read in the computation is changed).

Therefore, when the reactive variable is set in the event handler, the helpers are re-run and the template reflects the new value.

These are all fundamental to Meteor and are explained in the full Meteor documentation and in many resources.

Comment: I actually do have reactive data from clicking the <li> elements. I have event listeners that add/remove "active" class when clicking them. And everything is working fine except for the if clauses.

Comment: Having event listeners does not make reactive by itself. You can think of a reactive data source as one that invalidates computations when it changes. Manipulating stuff with jQuery is, in most cases, not a particularly good way to go when it comes to using Meteor.

Comment: Well then what is a good way to go using standard Meteor? I know this is possible without it, as it's a VERY simple task. I'm simply trying to render templates based on clicking navigation buttons. That is literally the simplest task I can even think of. I'm surprised this is so difficult.

Comment: I don't know how I could simplify this anymore. I don't need a "solution" for the exact problem I'm having. I need ANY method of achieving this desired outcome. 

I have nav-tabs that change "active" class. I want to render separate templates based on which one is active. I could do that with Jquery in my sleep but I'm trying to use templating to achieve it because it's much cleaner.

Comment: I think that everything that you need is in the code that I posted. I don't think that it is exceptionally complicated: 1 reactive variable to hold the current tab's index, one event listener, a few helpers to provide the tab data and reactively set the `active` class and the dynamic template helper. What seems to be missing?

Comment: You are using ecmascript and workarounds instead of using standard out-of-the-box Meteor reactive templating. This is a very easy problem with a very easy solution that Meteor can accomplish on its own. If I use your workaround I won't learn what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Using EcmaScript2015 is fairly standard these days. It actually simplifies the code such that I can use the shorthand notation for objects, arrow functions and better scoping for variables, and makes the code more future-proof. This is not at all an issue, and everything can be written (with a bit more verbosity) in ES5. Simply issue `meteor add ecmascript`. Reactive variables are also a standard way of doing things. No workarounds here, only best parctices.

Comment: I guess I must learn how to use ecmascript. You see, I just recently learned javascript/html/css and meteor. I didn't even know what HTML was 2 months ago. Therefore I'm trying to learn one thing at a time and new things I tend to put off until I have a greater understanding of what I'm currently working on. I guess I'll have to find some reading material on ecma

Comment: What is commonly referred to as JavaScript is, in fact, EcmaScript.

Comment: I appreciate all of your help. But you still don't seem to understand the REAL issue here. The issue is: I do not understand. The entire point of helping someone fix an issue is explaining it so they can understand. this ecmascript solution blows my mind. I have no idea what any of your code means. It looks like an entirely different language to me. Whether it IS or not doesn't matter. 

So long as I do not understand what is going on with your code and your solution, I will never be able to solve this problem myself, therefore none of your assistance aids me.

Comment: Are you telling me that there is no way possible for me to simply render a template based on a DOM element CLASS value, UNLESS I use ecmascript?

Comment: Very well. I changed the syntax to ES5 (JavaScript) and added some things that I hope will clear things up. It is difficult to tell one's depth of knowledge by a few lines of question. That's why I asked what's not clear.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. That clarified things a bit for me. Though your level of JavaScript expertise is far beyond my comprehension at the moment. Luckily, I ended up fixing it by using Sessions. It was quite easy and now I feel dumb for the 6 hours of struggle. Thanks again.